# Next image using PHP

Tags: php, html

I have image galleries based on tables, as follows:

```
<table id="gallery"> 
<tr>
<td><a href="largeimg.php?imageID=images/seascape/medium.Vietnam 19.jpg&caption= Vietnam, Cat Ba Island, Vietnam - 2015"><img src="images/seascape/thumb.Vietnam 19.jpg" height="75" ></a></td>
<td><a href="largeimg.php?imageID=images/seascape/medium.Vietnam 17.jpg&caption= Vietnam, Cat Ba Island, Vietnam - 2015"><img src="images/seascape/thumb.Vietnam 17.jpg" height="75" ></a></td>
<td><a href="largeimg.php?imageID=images/seascape/medium.Vietnam 14.jpg&caption= Vietnam, Cat Ba Island, Vietnam - 2015"><img src="images/seascape/thumb.Vietnam 14.jpg" height="75" ></a></td>
</tr>
```

And then on the page largeimg.php I use this to retrieve image id and caption to display the chosen image:

```
<figure>
<img src="<?php echo $_GET['imageID']; ?>">
<figcaption class="big"><?php echo $_GET['caption']; ?></figcaption>
</figure>
```

Is there a simple way using PHP to add the functionality of being able to browse through the gallery using "Previous" and "Next" buttons?

Comment: look into pagination or jQuery

Comment: The only way to do this with server side code like PHP is to reload the page on the _next_ and _previous_ commands. You would need something like a query string (i.e. `?img=1`) to be attached to the end of the url. Then increment or decrement the numer based on the action and reload the whole page. You'll definitely take a performance hit this way though. In short, use JavaScript on the client side...

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking to do will require you to use client side technologies. Remember that PHP is interpreted server side, therefore you will need to use a client side language such as Javascript (i'd recommend jQuery) to make that happen. You would also want to look into paginating your images as it may be a huge load to load all of them at once.

For what you are trying to do, I would even go as far as looking into Angular js. If your project is worth your time, i would definitely look into using angular for an image gallery, but of course this is just my personal opinion.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , it is possible.
For example , you have tables named as galleries and photos.
Your photos names are 1.png,2.png,3.png and all these images belong to one gallery and its id is 2.

Control current image index like this

```
if(isset($_GET["i"])){
    $i = intval($_GET["i"]);
    if($i<0){
      $i=0;
    }
}else{
    $i = 0;
} 
$next = $i+1;
$prev = $i-1;
```

Then , you can write a query like

```
select name from photos where gallery_id = 2 limit=1 offset=$i
```

According to this result , store current photo name in array like below

```
$curr_photo = $mysqli->query("select name from photos where gallery_id = 2 limit =1 offset=".$i);
```

Last , create next and previous photo links like below

```
<a href="gallery.php?id=2&i=<?php echo $prev;?>">Prev</a>
<a href="gallery.php?id=2&i=<?php echo $next;?>">Next</a>
```